# Can I have web deploy just use a static web.config that overwrites completely?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I don't like fighting with xdt transforms because that is overkill for me and can consume quite a bit of time. Its MUCH easier to just have a complete copy of web.config for each profile and statically code in the changes.

For example I have a config profile and a publish profile (MyNewProfile) and I want my publish profile to just use the Web.MyNewProfile.config when it is deployed.

But I would like to have Web.MyNewProfile.config as just plain text- just a straight web.config file. So no transforming is happening its just replacing the Web.config completely with what I have in Web.MyNewProfile.config.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just target the entire configuration element in your Web.WhateverTransform.config file to transform as a replacement and then paste whatever you want inside of that element... It's not exactly what you've asked for, but it seems like a fair work-around. There's only one transform call and then your entire config file is transformed to whatever you want it to be, satisfying my understanding of your main objective: output a web.config with the content of a web.Another.config while eliminating the need to constantly babysit the transform calls.

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="Replace">
  <!-- this will be the only element within the configuration node post-transform -->
  <thing></thing>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Web Deploy system in Visual Studio will do this for you (I could be wrong... hopefully someone will correct me), but you can just let Web Deploy run without any transforms, and then manually copy your own config file over top of the deployed file as soon as Web Deploy is finished, and if you want to get real fancy you can script this out yourself.

Comment: "manually copy your own config file over top of the deployed file as soon as Web Deploy is finished", I'll resort to transforms before doing that. I guess I'm just surprised I can't have this out of the box. This would be even simpler for MS to implement than transforms.

Comment: Also, this isn't exactly the VS system it is msbuild and msdeploy as far as I understand it

Comment: You just need to transform a higher level element, like <configuration> as a full replacement. It's not the same thing as running without transforms, but it's effectively producing the output that the OP wants.

Comment: what would that looks like? That does sounds like what I want

Comment: See the answer that I added. It would look almost exactly like your web.config does now but with an xdt:Transform="Replace" on the configuration element.